# Is eBay webhook option available? How to configure webhook URL in eBay?

Tags: java

How do I trigger the eBay API call, when new order is created. Is there any webhooks function exist? I want to get the new order details, when created. In eBay documentation doesn't tell about hooks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Search for eBay notifications.
It is the eBay name for webhooks